# VLC 2.0.3.. can't enable http interface

Tags: server, vlc

I'm new to linux world, and happy with my ubuntu 12.04 64-bit server.

I am working in a re-streaming project and got stuck around access the stream in the server.

Already fixed quite issues, except the web interface! All the methods I found is about a GUI preferences panel. What about the command line?

Any help?